# org.dom4j.DocumentException: Stream closed Nested exception: Stream closed

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom4j

When parsing valid XML file

```
private static boolean isXml(FileReader f) {

    try {
        saxReader.read(f);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        logger.warn("  - File is not XML: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I can't quite understand though, why that is and can't find a java doc explaining this.

Have you seen something like this before? This exception thrown on a valid XML file that is:

```
org.dom4j.DocumentException: Stream closed Nested exception: Stream closed
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:458)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:353)
```

Comment: No. Java app running on Linux parsing an XML file

Comment: Okay, never mind then. There was this [web page](http://www.iteye.com/problems/48352) suggesting that it would not work on Android, producing the exact same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileReader was already closed before you called the method.